.NET Get object to pass to method<T>
I have a service that reads messages from a queue. Now I want to deserialize this message based on what the current config file is. I determine what type it needs to be like this:
    public Type GetDistributionType()
    {
       Enum.TryParse(distributionOptions.DistributionType, out DistributionType distroType);
       return distroType switch
       {
           DistributionType.beer=> typeof(BeerDTO),
           DistributionType.wine => typeof(WineDTO),
           _ => throw new KeyNotFoundException("DistributionType"),
       };
    }

And I want to deserialize the message:
 public T Deserialize<T>(string value) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value) ?? throw new NullReferenceException();

I want to give the correct object to the generic deserializer.
private bool HandleMessage(string content)
{
   var type = _serialization.GetDistributionType();
   var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   var deserializedObject = _serialization.Deserialize<instance>(content);
   //rest of code
}

Now I get the error "instance is a variable but is used like a type"
How can I properly determine the DTO object and give an instance of it to the deserializer?

The problem is you use variable, where the type is expected.
You can use overload of JsonSerializer.Deserialize accepting Type as parameter:
private bool HandleMessage(string content)
{
   var type = _serialization.GetDistributionType();
   var deserializedObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(content, type);
   //rest of code
}

Or, if you're using JsonConvert: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject:
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, type);

